# Can’t set up a cluster in Centos7

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to set up a cluster on my Centos7.
and this is my elasticsearch.yml.

```
    ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
cluster.name: Winoc logger

------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#Use a descriptive name for the node:
node.name: Centos1

#Add custom attributes to the node:
#node.attr.rack: r1

---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
network.host: 192.168.0.120
transport.host: localhost

#Set a custom port for HTTP:
#http.port: 9200

#For more information, consult the network module documentation.
----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#path.data: /path/to/data

#Path to log files:
#path.logs: /path/to/logs

#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.0.120", "192.168.0.243"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes:
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
```

log:
https://ppt.cc/fVsg1x

another node of elasticsearch.yml has the same cluster name.
but the node can't find each other.

thank you in advance!

I check my firewalld and this is the log :

```
Jan 15 11:25:21 localhost.localdomain firewalld[916]: WARNING: ICMP type 'beyond-scope' is not supported by the kernel for ipv6.
    Jan 15 11:25:21 localhost.localdomain firewalld[916]: WARNING: beyond-scope: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
    Jan 15 11:25:21 localhost.localdomain firewalld[916]: WARNING: ICMP type 'failed-policy' is not supported by the kernel for ipv6.
    Jan 15 11:25:21 localhost.localdomain firewalld[916]: WARNING: failed-policy: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
    Jan 15 11:25:21 localhost.localdomain firewalld[916]: WARNING: ICMP type 'reject-route' is not supported by the kernel for ipv6.
    Jan 15 11:25:21 localhost.localdomain firewalld[916]: WARNING: reject-route: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
```

Comment: What is your firewall settings for both nodes? Which ports have been opened?

Comment: I have stopped both nodes firewall.

Comment: Could you check the connection from one another? e.g.: from node 192.168.0.120 -> telnet 192.168.0.243 9300, and other way around from 192.168.0.243

Comment: [wlogger@localhost bin]$ telnet 192.168.0.243
Trying 192.168.0.243...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.243: Connection refused

Comment: [wlogger@localhost bin]$ telnet 192.168.0.120
Trying 192.168.0.120...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.120: No route to host.

Comment: it seems they can't connect each other : (

Comment: oh ..    after I stop the firewall and it can run now!  thank you very much.